# How can I implement a custom jqGrid delete button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have added a delete button for each row into my jqGrid. Now I need to add functionality to those buttons. Each button has to delete the row which it is in and remove data from the server.  How can I do this?  Here is my code so far:

```
var lastsel;

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
        url: '@Url.Action("Category1List")',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['Navn', 'Slet'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'Navn', index: 'Navn', width: 50,edittype: 'text', align: 'center', editable: true , key: true },
            { name: 'act', index: 'act', width: 75, sortable: false}],
        gridComplete: function () {
            var ids = jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
            for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                var cl = ids[i];
                be = "<input style='height:22px;width:90px;' type='button' value='Slet' onclick=\"jQuery('#list').deleteRow('" + cl + "');\"  />";
                jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], { act: be });
            }
        },

        onSelectRow: function (id) {
            if (id && id !== lastsel) {
                jQuery('#list').jqGrid('restoreRow', lastsel);
                jQuery('#list').jqGrid('editRow', id, true);
                lastsel = id;
            }
        },
        editurl: '@Url.Action("GridSave")',
        rowNum: 50000,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
        pager: '#page',
        sortname: 'Id',
        sortorder: "desc",
        viewrecords: true,
        height: "500px"
    });
});
```

Comment: is `Slet` the value of your delete button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [delGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#delgridrow) method fore example. To do this you can just replace in your code `jQuery('#list').deleteRow(` to `jQuery('#list').jqGrid('delGridRow',`

You can consider to use `formatter:'actions'`: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622779/custom-jqgrid-post-action/6627201#6627201), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196387/jqgrid-editactioniconscolumn-events/5204793#5204793) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049325/how-to-end-inline-edit-started-with-formatter-edit-action-button-if-other-row-is/7049942#7049942). One more way to implement custom buttons you will find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303471/browser-memory-usage-comparison-inline-onclick-vs-using-jquery-bind/5305904#5305904).

**UPDATED**: To send additional information during Delete operation you can use [delData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties2) parameter of [delGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#delgridrow) method:

```
be = "... onclick=\"jQuery('#list').deleteRow('" + cl +
  ",{delData:{Navn:'"+ jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getCell',cl,'Navn')+ "'});\"  />";
```

The expression `jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getCell',cl,'Navn')` will get the value from the 'Navn' column and `{delData:{Navn:'NavnValue'}` will add `Navn=NavnValue` parameter to the data send to the server.

**UPDATED 2**: Your main problem was that you used in the demo project **another version of the code as you posted in your question**. Your demo has

```
... onclick=\"jQuery('#list').jqGrid('delGridRow','" + rows + "',
```

instead of

```
... onclick=\"jQuery('#list').jqGrid('delGridRow','" + cl + "',
```

which is the first important error. The `rows` variable you set as `var rows = jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');` inside of `gridComplete`. At the time no row is selected, `rows = null` and you place `onclick=\"jQuery('#list').jqGrid('delGridRow','null'` in for all your buttons.

The next important problem: you should rename

```
public ActionResult deleteRow(String ProductId)
```

to

```
public ActionResult deleteRow(String id)
```

or use `prmNames: {id: 'ProductId'}` as additional jqGrid parameter.

Other common problems:

- You should modify `_Layout.cshtml` file. You should remove `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>` because you include **another** version of the jQuery (jquery-1.5.2.min.js) in the `Index.cshtml`
- You should close `<table id="list">` (add ) in the `Index.cshtml`.
- If you want to have pager in the grid (you used `jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', "#page", ...`) you should 1) add `<div id="page"></div>` in the `Index.cshtml` and add parameter `pager: '#page'` to the jqGrid.
- You have to clean the HTML markup which you use. For example you should remove `</div>` from the end of `Index.cshtml`. One more `</div>` at the end of `@RenderSection("Main", required: false)</div>` (in the `_Layout.cshtml` file) should be also removed.
- To see the pager in the correct width you should include in the `_Layout.cshtml` file the following fix

  `<style type="text/css">input.ui-pg-input { width: auto; }</style>`
- You should include at least jQuery UI CSS and `ui.jqgrid.css` for example in the `_Layout.cshtml` file:

I would recommend you to replace `jquery-1.5.2.min.js` to `jquery-1.6.2.min.js`. The last version of `vsdoc` files you can always load from [here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx#jQuery_Releases_on_the_CDN_0). In the same way the last version (currently 1.8.16) of jQuery UI is also recommended.

I would recommend you to download [the VS2010 demo project](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridDemoVS2010.zip) which I created for [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500805/asp-net-mvc-2-0-implementation-of-searching-in-jqgrid/5501644#5501644) and use it as the template for your project. You can easy change the code to use Razor.

Comment: Okay now ive got it to respond and delete rows, but now i have to get it to delete a raw inside of my server, so i need to send "Navn" with my delete oeration

Comment: Problem which i have is that i cant sendt the data futher to my controller.

Comment: @Timsen: You should describe your problem more exactly. Do you realy not send the data or the controller not read the data? Till now you don't include any server side code in your question. You can examine the HTTP traffic with respect of [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Comment: okay, sorry

The thing i want is to send SellerId value to controller when i press delete in my jqgrid, so i can delete it in my controller. Just like you do when u are making edit

Comment: @Timsen: I don't see any `SellerId` in the jqGrid definition. If you fill jqGrid with `SellerId` as the id (rowid), the `id` value will be automatically send to the server. It will be done for Delete operation in the same way like for Edit or Add operations. You can rename the `id` parameter to `SellerId` with respect of `prmNames: {id:"SellerId"}` parameter of jqGrid. Just verify what will be currently send to the server. If you want to have the data in another format you should describe in which one format you need the data.

Comment: You can read my new code above, where i have some differences

Comment: You can read my new code above, where i have some differences, right now whet i am clicking on delete button in a row, im sending reference to delGridRow inside of my controller class. Controller class have String SellerKey as a incoming paramter but when im running the grid my sellerkey parameter inside of controller is null where delGridRow is called

Comment: @Timsen: OK, now I have found the code. Please **append** always the code to your question instead of writing the answer on your own question. To solve your problem you should just either rename `SellerKey` parameter from your controller action to `id` or to add `prmNames: {id:"SellerKey"}` parameter to the jqGrid. By the way you don't need to name the controller action as `delGridRow`. The `delGridRow` is jqGrid method which work on your client code. The `url` parameter of  `delGridRow` method should be just set to the controller action.

Comment: Thanks for fast answers, i tryed to use built in id, but its still wont work, at debuging, i can see that in controller sellerkey value is still null

Comment: @Timsen: Do you tried [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)? It's important to know *where* you have the problem: on the server side or on the client side. Moreover it is always helpful to open the source code of the generated page in the web browser. If the delete action on the controller will be called correctly you can have some problems in the MVC routing (look at `MapRoute` which you use in the `RegisterRoutes`).

Comment: It is a locla SQL server i have running, when i look into the source code, i can that rows property is null, so jqgrid doesnt get the value from a selected row

Comment: @Timsen: Only the tracing of HTTP traffic (with Fiddler for example) can gives you enough information whether you have the problem on the server or on the client part. If you upload somewhere your test project I could debug it on my computer and say you where you made an error.

Comment: here is a simple demo, layout is not pretty, but all the functionallity are there, ill hope ull finde some kind of solution oleg, im beign fighting with it all my weekend. http://www.2shared.com/file/5cQvo8Fd/MvcApplication3.html

Comment: oh almost forgot, u can use northwind database with it

Comment: @Timsen: I appended my answer.

Comment: One more question, now i want to make buttons to hyperlinks with same functionallity since buttons looks very ugly in grid, is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("#classOfYourButton").click(function(e){

e.stopPropagation();
$(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

Comment: add a class to your delete button and replace that name with `classOfYourButton` on click it will remove the `tr`