# jqGrid change dynamically edittype for specific row

Tags: jqgrid, cell

Following to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535942/solved-jqgrid-how-to-set-custom-editoptions-based-on-initial-column-values) where I found some way to do that I would want to get, I meet some trouble with it.
Here is my code :

```js
var myDlg = $("#dlgpers"),lastsel;
myDlg.jqGrid({
    url:'pers.php?id='+dataRow.id,
    mtype:'GET',
    datatype: "json",
    ajaxGridOptions: { cache: false },
    height:250,
    cmTemplate: {sortable:false},
    gridview: true,
    cellEdit:true,
    scroll:false,
    colNames:['Id','Label','Information','Type','Data'],
    colModel:[ 
        {name:'id',index:'id',hidden:true,key:true},
        {name:'label',index:'label',align:'right',width:100,editable:false,
            cellattr: function (rowId, val, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
                return ' style="font-weight:bold;margin-right:5px;border-left:0;border-top:0;" class="ui-state-active"' ;
            }
        },
        {name:'info',index:'info',width:200,editable:true,edittype:'text'},
        {name:'type',index:'type',width:30,hidden:true},
        {name:'data',index:'data',width:30,hidden:true}
    ],
    loadComplete: function () {
        var rowIds = myDlg.jqGrid('getDataIDs');
        $.each(rowIds, function (i, row) {
            var rowData = myDlg.jqGrid('getRowData',row);
            if (rowData.type == 'select') {
                myDlg.jqGrid('restoreRow', row);
                var cm = myDlg.jqGrid('getColProp', 'info');
                cm.edittype = 'select';
                cm.editoptions = { value: rowData.data };
                myDlg.jqGrid('editRow', row);
                cm.edittype = 'text';
                cm.editoptions = null;
                cm.editable = true;
            }else{
                myDlg.jqGrid('restoreRow', row);
                var cm = myDlg.jqGrid('getColProp', 'info');
                cm.edittype = 'text';
                cm.editoptions = null;
                cm.editable = true;
                myDlg.jqGrid('editRow', row);
                cm.edittype = 'text';
                cm.editoptions = null;
                cm.editable = true;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

and the result as image :

[image]

and the JSON response :

```js
{"page":1,"total":1,"records":1,"rows":[
{"cell":[0,"Nom ","LEBRUN","text",""]},
{"cell":[1,"Pr\u00e9nom ","Jacques","text",""]},
{"cell":[2,"Initiales ","LJ","text",""]},
{"cell":[3,"Fonction ","","text",""]},
{"cell"[4,"Service,"Administratif","select","0:Administratif;1:Commercial;2:Magasin;3:M\u00e9canique;4:Rejointage;5:Soudure;6:Tests"]},
{"cell":[5,"T\u00e9l\u00e9phone ","","text",""]},
{"cell":[6,"Email ","","text",""]},
{"cell":[7,"Statut ","CDI","select","0:CDI;1:CDD;2:App;3:Stg;4:Int"]},
{"cell":[8,"Entr\u00e9 le ","2008-10-06","text",""]},
{"cell":[9,"Sorti le ","0000-00-00","text",""]}]}
```

Two questions I submit to your knowledge:

1. As you can see, the second line (Prénom) don't seem editable, but it is.
2. I don't understand why these inputs are visible, as I would want they appear only if I edit some cell.

Many thanks for all your kind help for resolve (and explain) my wrong way.
JiheL

**UPDATED 2013-03-29**

I have applied your answer code and that run fine ! Many thanks.
But I have created another form in such a way for another subject, and that cause me some troubles.

Here is the code of this new form :

```
        var showAbs=function(){
        $('#EditDialog').empty();
        var $table=$('<table></table>')
        .attr('id','dlgcong')
        .appendTo($('#EditDialog'));
        var myCong = $("#dlgcong");
        myCong.jqGrid({
            url:'xpabs.php?id='+id+'&y='+y,
            datatype: "json",
            height:"auto",
            cmTemplate: {sortable:false},
            gridview: true,
            colNames:['Type absence','Début','Fin','id'],
            colModel:[ 
                {name:'abs',index:'abs',width:155,editable:true,edittype:'select',
                    editoptions:{ 
                        dataUrl:"selabs.php", 
                    dataEvents: [
                            {
                                type: 'change',
                                fn: function(e) {
                                    $(this).parent().css('background-color','#'+$(this).find('option:selected').attr('colr'));
                                    if($(this).find('option:selected').attr('colr')=='ffffff'){
                                        $(this).parent().parent().find('input').datepicker('disable');
                                    }else{
                                        $(this).parent().parent().find('input').datepicker('enable');
                                        $(this).parent().parent().attr('changed',true);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    cellattr: function (rowId, val, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
                        return ' style="background-color:#'+rawObject[4]+';color:white;"';
                    }
                },
                {name:'debut',index:'debut',align:'center',width:70,editable:true},
                {name:'fin',index:'fin',align:'center',width:70,editable:true},
                {name:'id',index:'id',hidden:true}
            ],
            jsonReader: {
                cell: "", 
                root: function (obj) { 
                    return obj; 
                } 
            },                  
            loadComplete: function (data) {
                var $self = $(this),
                        cm = $self.jqGrid("getColProp", "debut"),
                        idPrefix = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "idPrefix"),
                        l = data.length,
                        i,
                        item;
                for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                    item = data[i];
                    cm.editoptions = {
                        dataInit: function(element) {
                            $(element).datepicker({
                                setDate:item[1],
                                minDate:'01/01/'+y,
                                maxDate:'31/12/'+y,
                                onSelect: function( selectedDate,inst ) {
                                    $(element).val(selectedDate );
                                    $(element).parent().parent().attr('changed',true);
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
                var cm = $self.jqGrid("getColProp", "fin");
                for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                    item = data[i];
                    cm.editoptions = {
                        dataInit: function(element) {
                            $(element).datepicker({
                                setDate:item[2],
                                minDate:'01/01/'+y,
                                maxDate:'31/12/'+y,
                                onSelect: function( selectedDate,inst ) {
                                    $(element).val(selectedDate );
                                    $(element).parent().parent().attr('changed',true);
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    }
                    $self.jqGrid("editRow", idPrefix + item[3]);
                }
                myCong.find('select').each(function(){
                    $(this).css({
                        backgroundColor:'transparent',
                        color:'white',
                        border:0,
                        width:155
                    });
                });
            },
            idPrefix: "cong",
            rowNum: 10000   
        });
        //********************
        //  Button ' Valider '
        //********************
        $('<input />')
        .attr({
            type:'button',          
        })
        .css({
            float:'right',
            marginTop:'5px'
        })
        .click(function(){
            var toBeSaved='';
            myCong.find('tr[changed=true]').each(function(idx){
                if(toBeSaved.length>0){
                    toBeSaved+='|';
                }
                toBeSaved+=$(this).find('td:eq(3)').text()+';';
                toBeSaved+=$(this).find('select option:selected').val()+';';
                toBeSaved+=$(this).find('input:eq(0)').val()+';';
                toBeSaved+=$(this).find('input:eq(1)').val();
            });
            if(toBeSaved.length>0){
                $.ajax({
                    url:'majpabs.php?id='+id+'&data='+toBeSaved,
                    async:false,
                    dataType:'json',
                    success:function(data){
                        myGrid.trigger('reloadGrid');
                        $('#newAbs').val(' Nouveau ').attr('disabled',false);
                    }
                });
            }
        })
        .val(' Valider les absences ')
        .appendTo($('#EditDialog'));
        //*******************
        //  Button ' Retour '
        //*******************
        $('<input />')
        .attr({
            type:'button',
            id:'newAbs'
        })
        .css({
            float:'left',
            marginTop:'5px'
        })
        .click(function(){
            showPers();
        })
        .val(' Retour ')
        .appendTo($('#EditDialog'));
        //********************
        //  Button ' Nouveau '
        //********************
        $('<input />')
        .attr({
            type:'button',
            disabled:false
        })
        .css({
            float:'left',
            marginTop:'5px',
            marginLeft:'7px'
        })
        .click(function(){
            if($(this).val()==' Nouveau '){
                var myRow = {abs:"0", debut:'00/00/'+y, fin:'00/00/'+y, id:'0'};
                myCong.jqGrid('addRowData','',myRow, 'last');
                $(this).val(' Sauver ').attr('disabled',true);
            }else{
            }
        })
        .val(' Nouveau ')
        .appendTo($('#EditDialog'));
    }
```

and the result as image :

[image]

1. As you can see, the first row does not receive select and datepicker as other rows. Strange !
2. When I add new row, it does not receive select and datepicker as the first row. 
   I think I'm wrong in understanding this method.

I'm worry to bother you with these questions, I had a look in wiki without success to find any way to make these points correct. I would like to find some more detailed tutorial which show some cases examples.

Thank you **VERY MUCH** if you can spend again some time for give me a way to be more efficient with jqGrid.JiheL

**UPDATED 2013-04-01**

I have applied Oleg's suggestions and that works now. But a trouble remains.
here is the image :

[image]

For the first row, select box is OK. 
The first input field receive datepicker, but the second (the column called 'fin') not !
All others rows receive well datepickers, but not the last field of first row.
Here is the code :

```
                loadComplete: function (data) {
                var $self = $(this),
                        idPrefix = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "idPrefix"),
                        l = data.length,
                        i,
                        item,
                        cm;
                for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                    item = data[i];
                    cm = $self.jqGrid("getColProp", "debut");
                    cm.editoptions = {
                        dataInit: function(element) {
                            //alert('deb'+i);
                            $(element).datepicker({
                                setDate:item[1],
                                minDate:'01/01/'+y,
                                maxDate:'31/12/'+y,
                                onSelect: function( selectedDate,inst ) {
                                    $(element).val(selectedDate );
                                    $(element).parent().parent().attr('changed',true);
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    };
                    $self.jqGrid("editRow", idPrefix + item[3]);
                    //
                    cm = $self.jqGrid("getColProp", "fin");
                    cm.editoptions = {
                        dataInit: function(element) {
                            //alert('fin'+i);
                            $(element).datepicker({
                                setDate:item[2],
                                minDate:'01/01/'+y,
                                maxDate:'31/12/'+y,
                                onSelect: function( selectedDate,inst ) {
                                    $(element).val(selectedDate );
                                    $(element).parent().parent().attr('changed',true);
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    };
                    $self.jqGrid("editRow", idPrefix + item[3]);
                }
                myCong.find('select').each(function(){
                    $(this).css({
                        backgroundColor:'transparent',
                        color:'white',
                        border:0,
                        width:155
                    });
                });
            },
```

Another time, I hope you can help me to resolve this trouble and close this request.
Many thanks for all the time you spend to help newbies.
JiheL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that many from the problems in your code common. So I tried to answer on you question more detailed.

First of all you posted wrong JSON data. The line

```js
{"cell"[4,"Service,"Administratif","select","0:Administratif;1:Commercial;2:Magasin;3:M\u00e9canique;4:Rejointage;5:Soudure;6:Tests"]},
```

contains two errors:

1. no ':' after "cell"
2. no `"` after `"Service`

After the changes the line will be so

```js
{"cell":[4,"Service","Administratif","select","0:Administratif;1:Commercial;2:Magasin;3:M\u00e9canique;4:Rejointage;5:Soudure;6:Tests"]},
```

and JSON data could be read. The next problem is the usage of numbers together with string in one array. Because the bug in [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/js/grid.base.js#L1384) of jqGrid code

```js
idr = ccur !== undefined ? ccur[idn] || idr : idr;
```

ids could not be integer value 0. I posted [the bug report](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/small-bug-with-reading-id0/#p28519) about the error. **To fix the problem using *existing code* of jqGrid you should use strings instead of numbers**. For example the line

```js
{"cell":[0,"Nom ","LEBRUN","text",""]},
```

should be changed to

```js
{"cell":["0","Nom ","LEBRUN","text",""]},
```

Without the changes you will have **id duplicates**. Both first lines (`{"cell":[0,"Nom ","LEBRUN","text",""]}` and `{"cell":[1,"Pr\u00e9nom ","Jacques","text",""]},`)  will get the same id equal to 1 instead of 0 and 1. **It was the main reason of the problem which you described.**

Additionally I would recommend you the following:

- **remove `cellEdit:true` option**. You use `editRow` later in the code. It means that you use [inline editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing) instead of [cell editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing) which means `cellEdit:true`. You can't combine both editing modes in one grid.
- replace `height:250` option to `height:"auto"`
- remove all `index` properties from `colModel`. Remove all properties of `colModel` with default values (`edittype:'text'`, `editable:false`)
- remove options of jqGrid with default values (`mtype:'GET'`, `scroll:false`)
- all parameters of functions in JavaScript are *optional*. So if you don't use for example any parameters of `cellattr` callback you can replace `cellattr: function (rowId, val, rawObject, cm, rdata) {...}` to `cellattr: function () {...}`
- the callback `loadComplete` has one parameter `data` which can provide you all data which returned from the server. So you don't need to use `getDataIDs` and `getRowData`. The array `data.rows` can by directly used.
- if you use `data` parameter of `loadComplete` callback you can remove unneeded `'type'` and `'data'` columns from the grid.
- if you place information about `id` after `'Label','Information'` then you can use `id` property of `jsonReader` and remove hidden `id` column from the grid too. For example if you move `id` as the last in the `cell` array you can use `jsonReader: {id: 4}` and remove hidden `id` column from the grid. If you add additionally `cell: ""` property in `jsonReader` you can remove `"cell":` from the input data. If you would use `root` property of `jsonReader` defined as function (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#jsonreader_as_function)) you can remove some unneeded data from the server response.

For example the server can produce the simplified data

```js
[
["Nom ","LEBRUN","text","","0"],
["Pr\u00e9nom ","Jacques","text","","1"],
["Initiales ","LJ","text","","2"],
["Fonction ","","text","","3"],
["Service","Administratif","select","0:Administratif;1:Commercial;2:Magasin;3:M\u00e9canique;4:Rejointage;5:Soudure;6:Tests","4"],
["T\u00e9l\u00e9phone ","","text","","5"],
["Email ","","text","","6"],
["Statut ","CDI","select","0:CDI;1:CDD;2:App;3:Stg;4:Int","7"],
["Entr\u00e9 le ","2008-10-06","text","","8"],
["Sorti le ","0000-00-00","text","","9"]
]
```

The corresponding jqGrid could be

```js
$("#dlgpers").jqGrid({
    url: "pers.php?id=" + dataRow.id,
    datatype: "json",
    height: "auto",
    cmTemplate: {sortable: false},
    gridview: true,
    colNames: ["Label", "Information"],
    colModel: [
        {name: "label", align: "right", width: 100,
            cellattr: function () {
                return ' style="font-weight:bold;margin-right:5px;border-left:0;border-top:0;" class="ui-state-active"';
            }},
        {name: "info", width: 200, editable: true}
    ],
    jsonReader: {id: 4, cell: "", root: function (obj) { return obj; } },
    loadComplete: function (data) {
        var $self = $(this),
            cm = $self.jqGrid("getColProp", "info"),
            idPrefix = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "idPrefix"),
            l = data.length,
            i,
            item;

        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            item = data[i];
            cm.edittype = item[2] === "select" ? "select" : "text";
            cm.editoptions = { value: item[3] };
            $self.jqGrid("editRow", idPrefix + item[4]);
        }
    },
    idPrefix: "dlg",
    rowNum: 10000 // to have no paging
});
```

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user2132268_1_.htm):

[image]

Comment: Sorry for late answer I was on business move. Many thanks for your kind help ! You really are THE great master of jqGrid because your knowledge is great and you quickly answer for helping newbies. I have some trouble in applying your demo, I explain in UPDATED question. JiheL

Comment: @user2132268: You are welcome! I suggested you in my answer to change numeric `id` to string `id` in the server response (like `0` to `"0"` in my answer). It should fix the problem with first row which are without drop-down. What JSON data returns the server now? Another problem is that you used *two* loops inside of `loadComplete`. You have to have *one* loop where you change *temporary* property of `editoptions` for some columns and *inside of the loop* call `editRow` which will use the last values of `editoptions`. You current code will use only the value of *last* item of data fro `debut`.

Comment: Thank you Oleg for remembering this point. One more time you saved time and I did not worry you. Therefore I have yet a problem, I update my question for explaining. Many thanks. JiheL